# Programing a password or code system where a code can only be used a set amount of times

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

**Intro:**
I want to be able to have a system where a person can purchase a code from my store and that code or password can be used on my PHP website. But each time that code is used the amount of given uses on that code will be decreed so when it has been used up the code will be no longer usable.

**Example:**
My shop is selling a 5 use forum un-ban code.

The person goes and buys that code and is given a random generated diet code EX: 91259102

The person goes to the redemption site and enters that purchased code.

Once the code has been used that one time the code will only have 4 uses remaining on it.

Once the user has used the code 4 more times the code is no longer valid.

**What I want to be able to do:**
Generate codes via a PHP website. (no need to be automatically generated)

Store the given codes on a .txt document on the server **or** using a MySQL database.

Have the user be able to use the codes on my website.

**Final:**
Thanks for any input I can get it is all much appreciated.

Thanks, Code Squishy.

Comment: ok, so write some code? no one is here to right your code for you.

Comment: Hi. "any input I can get" is not a valid SO question. Please read [ask] & other links at [help].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As suggested when you signed up, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to get a better idea of off- and on-topic questions. Your question is off-topic, as it's very broad in nature (lots of ways to solve it), and will only get you opinion and debate.

Answer (score -2):

Do not store it in a .txt file. That's extremely insecure and just asking for someone to steal all of the codes. If you forget to blacklist that file type, anyone could simply request it and read the contents. It also would be much more difficult to deal with a TXT file than it would a database such as MySQL. This is the kind've thing databases are written for, so luckily you're covered![1]

Additionally, randomly generating would be much easier, and likely safer than generating them yourself. You could use any standard number generator, and even just hash it with the md5[2] hashing algorithm to get standard length codes.

When a new code is generated, create a new entry in your database. All the table has to contain is two columns, the code as well as the amount of uses left. Each time the code is used, just subtract from that stored value. Once it reaches zero, remove the entry from the table in your database.

PHP has many constructs for accomplishing all of these. This is where I recommend you start:
[[1]MySQL and PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

[[2]PHP Hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)

I hope this helps!

Comment: You might store the purchasers username too.

Comment: 1) This isn't an answer. This is a few opinions on things. Please don't answer such broad, opinion-soliciting questions. 2) Please refrain from ever saying something should be "trivial." Programming is not trivial, especially for someone learning, and in this case learning not only php but also learning how to work with a database. This is the type of commentary that discourages people from programming, when someone says a task is easy or trivial, and then they can't solve it.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Fair points--I revised my post. I hope the answer is better, although I didn't think I had very many opinions in it minus the trivial statement. I understand how that may seem obnoxious though. Thanks!